# Sequelize: Cyclic dependency found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Dependency chain: relationships -> users => relationships

The goal is for Relationships to have a user_one, user_two, and last_user action. The standard user_one, user_two relationship works fine, but when I try to add in the last_user_action with Relationships.hasOne() I'm getting a dependency chain error. Is there a quick fix for this?

```
var Relationships = sequelize.define(
"Relationships",
{
  type: DataTypes.ENUM('block', 'follow', 'pending')
},
{ 
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Relationships.hasOne(models.Users, { as: 'lastUserAction', foreignKey: 'last_user_action' });
    }
  },
  tableName: "relationships"
}
);


var Users = sequelize.define(
"Users",
{
  firstName: DataTypes.STRING
},
{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Users.belongsToMany(models.Users, { as: 'userRelationship', through: models.Relationships, foreignKey: 'user_one_id', otherKey: 'user_two_id' });
    }
  },
  tableName: "users"
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Users.hasMany(models.Relationships, { as: 'lastUserAction', foreignKey: 'last_user_action' });
```

instead of Relationships.hasOne()